# In Leviticus 6:2 LXX, what is the meaning of κοινωνίας?

Tags: greek, word-study, grammar, leviticus

The NLT version of Leviticus 6:2, based on the Hebrew, has this:

> [Lev 6:2 NLT] (2) "Suppose one of you sins against your associate and is unfaithful to the LORD. Suppose you cheat in a deal involving **a security deposit**, or you steal or commit fraud,

[Brenton](https://studybible.info/Brenton/lev%206:2), based on the Greek, has this:

> Brenton(i) Lev 6:2 The soul which shall have sinned, and willfully overlooked the commandments of the Lord, and shall have dealt falsely in the affairs of his neighbour in the matter of a deposit [[παραθήκη]](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G3866&t=NLT), or concerning **fellowship**, or concerning plunder, or has in anything wronged his neighbour,

Thayer's has this:

> κοινωνία, κοινωνίας, ἡ ( κοινωνός), fellowship, association, community, communion, joint participation, intercourse; in the N. T. as in classical Greek

1. the share which one has in anything, participation; with the genitive of the thing in which he shares: πνεύματος, Philippians 2:1; τοῦ ἁγίου πνεύματος, 2 Corinthians 13:13 (14); τῶν παθημάτων τοῦ Χριστοῦ, Philippians 3:10; τῆς πίστεως, Philemon 1:6 (cf. Lightfoot); τοῦ ἱματος τοῦ Χριστοῦ, i. e. in the benefits of Christ's death, 1 Corinthians 10:16 (cf. Meyer at the passage); τοῦ σώματος τοῦ Χριστοῦ in the (mystical) body of Christ or the church, ibid.; τῆς διακονίας, 2 Corinthians 8:4; τοῦ μυστηρίου, Ephesians 3:9 Rec. εἰς κοινωνίαν τοῦ υἱοῦ τοῦ Θεοῦ, to obtain fellowship in the dignity and blessings of the Son of God, 1 Corinthians 1:9, where cf. Meyer.
2. intercourse, fellowship, intimacy: δεξιά κοινωνίας, the right hand as the sign and pledge of fellowship (in fulfilling the apostolic office), Galatians 2:9 (where see Lightfoot); τίς κοινωνία φωτί πρός σκότος; what in common has light with darkness? 2 Corinthians 6:14 ( τίς οὖν κοινωνία πρός Ἀπολλωνα τῷ μηδέν οἰκεῖον ἐπιτετηδευκοτι, Philo, leg. ad Gaium § 14 at the end; εἰ δέ τίς ἐστι κοινωνία πρός Θεούς ἡμῖν, Stobaeus, serm. 28 (i. p. 87, Gaisf. edition)); used of the intimate bond of fellowship which unites Christians: absolutely, Acts 2:42; with εἰς τό εὐαγγέλιον added, Philippians 1:5; κοινωνίαν ἔχειν μεθ' ἡμῶν, μετ' ἀλλήλων, 1 John 1:3, 7; of the fellowship of Christians with God and Christ, μετά τοῦ πατρός καί μετά τοῦ υἱοῦ αὐτοῦ, 1 John 1:3, 6, (which fellowship, according to John's teaching, consists in the fact that Christians are partakers in common of the same mind as God and Christ, and of the blessings arising therefrom). By a use unknown to secular authors κοινωνία in the N. T. denotes:
3. a benefaction jointly contributed, a collection, a contribution, as exhibiting an embodiment and proof of fellowship (cf. Grimm, Exeget. Hdbch. on Wisd. 8:18, p. 176): 2 Corinthians 8:4; εἰς τινα, for the benefit of one, 2 Corinthians 9:13; ποιεῖσθαι κοινωνία (to make a contribution) εἰς τινα, Romans 15:26; joined with εὐποιΐα, Hebrews 13:16. (Cf. Buttmann, § 132, 8.)

> > [THAYER’S GREEK LEXICON, Electronic Database.
> > Copyright © 2002, 2003, 2006, 2011 by Biblesoft, Inc.
> > All rights reserved. Used by permission. BibleSoft.com](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G2842&t=NLT)

[Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers](https://biblehub.com/leviticus/6-2.htm) has this:

> Or in fellowship.--Literally, or in something that is placed in the hand; that is, put in his hand, a deposit. It is similar in nature to the trust mentioned in the preceding clause, for which reason it is not repeated in the general recapitulation of the offences in Leviticus 6:4-5.

Answer (score 3):

I have found some comments that can be useful to your research, I hope.

The first is drawn from the Cambridge Bible; the second is drawn from an Italian essay not yet translated in English language (as far as I know).

Except you are able to read Italian (and to bump into this text), this comment will prove to be brand-new for you (the Italian-English translation is mine [let's hope...])

Anyway, the following bold is mine.

“The rendering of A.V., fellowship, is supported by LXX. and Syr., and means **partnership in any transaction agreed to by placing the hand in that of another**.” (*Cambridge Bible*)

“It is difficult to grasp the meaning of the expression, […]בתשׂומת   that occurs only here. The noun derives from the verb שׂומ/שׂימ; then, indicates something that can be ‘put’, or ‘placed’. Often, commentators mean this expression in the sense of ‘pledge’, ‘guarantee’; others think to a ‘borrowing’, instead. Rashi, beyond this meaning, proposed also the idea of **a capital entrusted to someone to doing a bargain**. The Septuagint seems to get this meaning when translates [the Hebrew term] with *κοινονια*, ‘**collective ownership**’. It is clear that here is facing us a technical term […].” (Giorgio Paximadi, in *Nuova Versione della Bibbia dai Testi Antichi*, Edizioni San Paolo, Milano, 2017, note on Lev 5:21)